# is there a way to change the value of json data? swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

actually I want to change the photo of my profile, but before I change the value of "profileImage" in one of json object , one photo uploaded , and i want to change the value of json object with photo that choosen by user from photo library, photo(address of photo) inside of "profilePhoto" must be change , what's your opinion ?

this is user json format :

```
["country": {
"__v" = 0;
"_id" = 606836832ed79e4194e98849;
name = emirate;
}, "_id": 60f27a3d6aba1b154a394acc, "email": leopard@gmail.com, "name": Leo   program, "city": {
"__v" = 0;
"_id" = 6068368d2ed79e4194e9884a;
countryId = 606836832ed79e4194e98849;
title = Dubai;
}, 
"address": this is the test address from programmer, "userName": Leopard, 
"profileImage": images/profile/2021-07-19T10-18-48.901Z-20px-Flag_of_the_Valencian_Community_(2x3).svg.png, 
"telephone": 09336322332]
```

and also here is my code and http request is PATCH and the key for image of profile is "image" :

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    
    if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        
        
        if let imageURL = info[.imageURL] as? URL {
           
            let asset = imageURL.description
            if asset.contains("file://") {
               let changableURl = asset.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "")
                URLOfImage = changableURl
                //let changableURl = asset
                print("this is image url like this: \(changableURl)")
                let parameters = [
                         [
                           "key": "image",
                           "src": "\(changableURl)",
                           "type": "file"
                         ]] as [[String : Any]]
               //changeImage(parameters: parameters)
                uploadImage(paramName: "image", fileName: changableURl, image: image)
            }
            
            print("this is the asset \(asset)")
           // print(asset?.value(forKey: "filename"))

        }
        
     // print("  this is url of image :   \(info.description) ")
        print("this isssssssssss \(info.values.description)")
        if (info[.mediaURL] != nil) {
                       print(" this is provided for you \(String(describing: info[.mediaURL]))")
                   }
        profileImage.image = image
        
// if  saveImage(image: image) == true {

//     print("this successeful photo image")
//
//   }
    } else if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        
       if let imageURL = info[.imageURL] as? URL {
      // let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [imageURL], options: nil)
       let asset = imageURL.description
      if asset.contains("file://") {
         let changableURl = asset.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "")
          //let changableURl = asset
           print(changableURl)
           let parameters = [
                    [
                      "key": "image",
                      "src": "\(changableURl)",
                      "type": "file"
                    ]] as [[String : Any]]
          //changeImage(parameters: parameters)
        uploadImage(paramName: "image", fileName: changableURl, image: image)
       }
       
       print("this is the asset \(asset)")
      // print(asset?.value(forKey: "filename"))

   }
        
        print("   this is a test   \(info.values.description)")
        if (info[.mediaURL] != nil) {
            print(" this is provided for you \(String(describing: info[.mediaURL]))")
        }

        print("  this is url of image :   \(info.description) ")

        profileImage.image = image
        
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
         
}
```

And also this is inside of my upload image on json :

```
func uploadImage(paramName: String, fileName: String, image: UIImage) {
  let url = URL(string: "https://api.offernews.co/api/user")

  // generate boundary string using a unique per-app string
  let boundary = UUID().uuidString

  let session = URLSession.shared

  // Set the URLRequest to POST and to the specified URL
  var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
  urlRequest.httpMethod = "PATCH"

  // Set Content-Type Header to multipart/form-data, this is equivalent to submitting form data with file upload in a web browser
  // And the boundary is also set here
  urlRequest.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

  var data = Data()

  // Add the image data to the raw http request data
  data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
  data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(paramName)\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
  data.append("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
  data.append(image.pngData()!)

  data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

  // Send a POST request to the URL, with the data we created earlier
  session.uploadTask(with: urlRequest, from: data, completionHandler: { responseData, response, error in
      if error == nil {
          let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData!, options: .allowFragments)
          if let json = jsonData as? [String: Any] {
              print(" this leatherface vs json : \(json)")
  //guard case let json["profileImage"] = UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.URLOfImage)! as UIImage else {
 //  return
 // }
            var profileImageName = json["profileImage"] as! UIImage
            profileImageName = UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.URLOfImage)!
           // json["profileImage"] = profileImageName
            //json["profileImage"] = UIImage(contentsOfFile: URLOfImage)
          }
      }
  }).resume()
  }
```

thank you so much for your help

Comment: "this my json format"  That's not in the JSON format.

Comment: @ElTomato your right brother ,but  I try to change the value of "photoProfile", what's your opinion?

Comment: but why you used local path while you upload the image. upload image will return `url`.

Comment: @jatinfl dear friend actually I'm beginner , I dont know what should I do I need some help about this

Comment: please run that (upload image)api on postman first and check response.

Comment: and if `images/profile/2021-07-19T10-18-48.901Z-20px-Flag_of_the_Valencian_Community_(2x3).svg.png` this one will return talk to backend developer to completed url from backend.

Comment: @ElTomato do you have any useful website or educating website  for PATCH an images on json file?

Answer (score 0):

Your json containing "profileImage" with utl and you trying to assign UIImage in this after getting response.

Need to do:-
Please get uploaded image url path in update api response with help of backend.

```
 yourJsonObject["profileImage"] = Uploaded image url which will you get from api.
```